# the most efficient and fastest way to compare elements in a vector?

Tags: c++, boost, vector, iterator

What is the most efficient and fastest way to compare elements in a vector of class using two iterators? The vector is not a sortable one and I have an overloaded ">" operator for the class. I use boost foreach for simple vector iterations.

I am doing something similar to the one given below.

```
vector<TestClass*> vec; 
vector<TestClass*>::iterator jIter;     
bool isErased=false;
vector<TestClass*>::iterator iIter = vec.begin();
if(!vec.empty()){
    while(iIter < vec.end()-1) {            
        isErased = false;
        for (jIter = iIter+1; jIter < vec.end();jIter++) {          
            if((*(*iIter))<=(*(*jIter))) {
                delete *jIter;
                jIter = vec.erase(jIter);               
                jIter--;
            }               
            else if((*(*iIter))>=(*(*jIter))) {                 
                delete *iIter;
                iIter = vec.erase(iIter);
                isErased = true;
                break;
            }               
        }
        if(!isErased) iIter++;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say the OP is trying to see if each element in the vector matches *any* other element and remove those that only exist once.

Comment: The most efficient and fastest way to do something is just to Not Do It. If you do things that are slow with vector, don't use vector. As for finding the maximum element of an array, use std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());

Comment: I don't understand why this question is attracting upvotes given that in its current form it is not possible to determine precisely what the OP was hoping to achieve.

Comment: Why isn't it sortable?  Why are you using a `vector`?  If you want uniqueness, then you should use a container that provides it (like `set` or `map`, or at the very least a _sorted_ `vector`.

Comment: Chad, Thank you for the inputs, First of all it is a vector of objects and not vector of sortable elements, second I dont want the change the order of the elements.

Comment: jrok/Flexo, I am sorry for the confusion I have given exact sample of code which I am trying to do.. I hope this will make some sense.. I just wan to know if there is much better way of doing this....

Answer (score 1):

The most tricky part is to avoid running into invalidated iterators:

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [j](T const &i) { return i > j; });
```

You *could* also employ a loop, but use reverse iterators in that case

PS: I can't grok what you *actually* wanted achieve in your algorithm

You might be interested in

- [is_sorted_until](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until)
- [partition_point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point)
- [adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find)

Comment: @111111 I clarified my _non-comprehension_ of the algorithm requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but something like this.

```
 for(auto it=vec.begin(), end=vec.end(); it!=end; ++it) {
   const auto&& val=*it;
   std::size_t count=0u;
   end=std::remove_if(
       it, end,
       [&](const TestClass& tc) -> bool {
           if(tc==val) ++count;
           return (count > 1);
       }
   );
 }
 vec.erase(end, vec.end());
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this doesn't do what the OP's sample did, either, on various points. (I don't blame you, I can't really make sense of what it is trying to achieve myself)

Comment: @sehe, haha, as far as I can tell he wants to remove duplicates, WITHOUT sorting the container, I don't know why he can't sort when he CAN mutate it. (Note i just made some edits, that make a bit more sense).